# XAMPP: MYSQL stops working after I restart

Tags: mysql, xampp

I am having problems with starting MYSQL in XAMPP. Apache starts alright but then MYSQL keeps reporting an unexpected shutdown.

I was led to delete `C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1` and it works after that but that deletes all my databases and MYSQL stops working again after I restart my machine.

I went through the error logs and this is what I saw:

> [ERROR] InnoDB: Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace.
>   Previous tablespace mysql/innodb_index_stats uses space ID: 2 at
>   filepath: .\mysql\innodb_index_stats.ibd. Cannot open tablespace
>   yiicrud/customer which uses space ID: 2 at filepath:
>   .\yiicrud\customer.ibd InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table
>   tablespace file .\yiicrud\customer.ibd InnoDB: We do not continue the
>   crash recovery, because the table may become InnoDB: corrupt if we
>   cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log to it. InnoDB: To fix
>   the problem and start mysqld: InnoDB: 1) If there is a permission
>   problem in the file and mysqld cannot InnoDB: open the file, you
>   should modify the permissions. InnoDB: 2) If the table is not needed,
>   or you can restore it from a backup, InnoDB: then you can remove the
>   .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal InnoDB: crash recovery and
>   ignore that table. InnoDB: 3) If the file system or the disk is
>   broken, and you cannot remove InnoDB: the .ibd file, you can set
>   innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf InnoDB: and force InnoDB to
>   continue crash recovery here.

Comment: How did you create/import the database 'yiicrud'?

Comment: i created it in phpmyadmin on the same machine

Comment: I experienced similar problem when I created a database in mysql 5.5 and then imported in mysql 5.6. The import worked ok but afterwards mysql wouldn't start. Had to downgrade mysql to 5.5 to continue the project :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot everyone.

I have able to solve it. It appears the database was created in a later version and was incompatible with this new version of xampp so i created the databases again and imported the tables into them. Previously I was importing the database with the create statements as well.

Had the idea from Salman's comment.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this line in my.cnf worked for me:

```
innodb_force_recovery = 1
```

Comment: for me 1 was not helpfull but I set `innodb_force_recovery = 6` in the /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/my.cnf about line 26 just after [mysqld] and it is resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution on this page: [XAMPP/MySQL: could not open single-table tablespace file .\mysql\innodb_index_stats.ibd after restart of MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18575755/xampp-mysql-could-not-open-single-table-tablespace-file-mysql-innodb-index-st)

> Move (DON'T DELETE) those files, into another folder:
>
> ```
> innodb_index_stats.frm <br>
> innodb_table_stats.frm <br>
> slave_worker_info.frm <br>
> slave_master_info.frm <br>
> slave_relay_log_info.frm <br>
> ```
>
> and .ibd files with the same filename.
>
> Try start MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. rename the `XAMMP\mysql\data` folder to any other name you wish (say `data_old` )
2. make a new folder in `XAMMP\mysql` name `data` and copy all the files in it including `ibdata1`
3. close all running programs and restart XAMPP

No need to copy files from `data_old` but if you do have previously constructed databases then you may copy some files from `data_old`.

The solution may come again. If it then you have to change the port to something else like `3308` in the config settings as well as in `phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php`.

If the problem stays still then its better to change the application which uses the port `3306` and set default settings in XAMPP.