# Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error... Prob with database i thnik( details: wamp,joomla)

Tags: mysql, database, wamp, joomla3.0

**Problem**
My problem started suddenly while I was working on my project. 
Next day I tried to prepare some details on my site,and when I tried to open the server I had a problem with the database and my problem was like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18575755/xampp-mysql-could-not-open-single-table-tablespace-file-mysql-innodb-index-st)...

After several days of search on web, I found a second database which I deleted it and after that the server works fine, but my project not...

I dont have access to back-end or front-end and displays this:
**"Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error"**.

**Database**
I know somethings going wrong with database i checked wamp mysql log which has a warning
:
[Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table database1/culiz_session from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
I checked this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html) and I couldnt find what option works for me.

**Conclusion**
Any advice how can I work again on my project because I was almost done with the page and I cant start again from the scratch...

**Details:**

Windows 7

Joomla 3.1.5

WAMPSERVER (32 BITS & PHP 5.4) 2.4
Apache : 2.4.4
MySQL : 5.6.12
PHP : 5.4.16
PHPMyAdmin : 4.0.4
SqlBuddy : 1.3.3
XDebug : 2.2.3

Answer (score 0):

Error displaying the error page should be a tip that there is no server available. Application Instantiation is the startup of the application failing - either because of the Apache server configuration, or because on or more of the the other server components isn't working or present ie. PHP or MySQL.

Suggest you make sure the WAMP server is running all the required services and is configured properly.