# Apache Running but MySQL does not start - WAMP

Tags: apache, wamp

I have `WAWMP` installed on `Win 7`. It was working well but since I restarted my system and I ran into a problem.

Problem is that `MySQL` is not starting but `Apache` is running as usual. When I `Test Port 80` it says *Apache is running*.

I have tried to change ports in `my.ini` of `MySQL` but still MySQL does not start.

Here is latest Log when I attempted to start `MySQL`

```
2014-06-18 08:15:23 4496 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2014-06-18 08:15:23 4496 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2014-06-18 08:15:23 4496 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2014-06-18 08:15:23 4496 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2014-06-18 08:15:23 4496 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2014-06-18 08:15:23 4496 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2014-06-18 08:15:23 4496 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2014-06-18 08:15:23 4496 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2014-06-18 08:15:24 4496 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1625977 and 1625977 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 22262437 in the ib_logfiles!
2014-06-18 08:15:24 4496 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2014-06-18 08:15:24 4496 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2014-06-18 08:15:24 4496 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2014-06-18 08:15:24 4496 [ERROR] InnoDB: Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace. Previous tablespace joomla_web/intern_extensions uses space ID: 104 at filepath: .\joomla_web\intern_extensions.ibd. Cannot open tablespace test/joomla_assets which uses space ID: 104 at filepath: .\test\joomla_assets.ibd
InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file .\test\joomla_assets.ibd
InnoDB: We do not continue the crash recovery, because the table may become
InnoDB: corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log to it.
InnoDB: To fix the problem and start mysqld:
InnoDB: 1) If there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld cannot
InnoDB: open the file, you should modify the permissions.
InnoDB: 2) If the table is not needed, or you can restore it from a backup,
InnoDB: then you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal
InnoDB: crash recovery and ignore that table.
InnoDB: 3) If the file system or the disk is broken, and you cannot remove
InnoDB: the .ibd file, you can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf
InnoDB: and force InnoDB to continue crash recovery here.
```

Comment: their seems to be a corruption in your files. did you close WAMP during a long import or something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [XAMPP/MySQL: could not open single-table tablespace file .\mysql\innodb\_index\_stats.ibd after restart of MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18575755/xampp-mysql-could-not-open-single-table-tablespace-file-mysql-innodb-index-st)

Answer (score 0):

try to goto control panel, administrative tool, services or run services.msc (shortcut) try to start and stop and restart MYSQL services.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved my problem by deleting the `ibdata1` file in `C:\WAMP\mysql\data`

For those who dont know what is [What is stored in ibdata1](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,588689,588689)

[Read this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/487159/what-is-the-ibdata1-file-in-my-var-lib-mysql-directory#487534)