# Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found

Tags: mysql, xampp

Guys I installed xampp with mysql yday. managed to created a simple db with a single table.

This morning, for some reason Apache is running in my control panel but mysql gives a 'Error:mySQL Shoudown unexpectedly.' Reading the log, apparently some "innodb_table_stats" cannot be found/reached. If it helps, I was playing with the my.cnf as discussed here ([MySQL Server has gone away when importing large sql file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12425287/mysql-server-has-gone-away-when-importing-large-sql-file)) yday.

Follows the full log.

```
2013-12-05 09:18:16 2660 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2013-12-05 09:18:16 124c InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2013-12-05 09:18:16 2660 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2013-12-05 09:18:16 2660 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2013-12-05 09:18:16 2660 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2013-12-05 09:18:16 2660 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2013-12-05 09:18:16 2660 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2013-12-05 09:18:16 2660 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2013-12-05 09:18:16 2660 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2013-12-05 09:18:16 2660 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 0 and 0 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 5602287 in the ib_logfiles!
2013-12-05 09:18:16 2660 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2013-12-05 09:18:16 2660 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2013-12-05 09:18:16 2660 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2013-12-05 09:18:17 2660 [ERROR] InnoDB: Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace. Previous tablespace intrasdata@00201@002e0@002e0/intrasextract uses space ID: 2 at filepath: .\intrasdata@00201@002e0@002e0\intrasextract.ibd. Cannot open tablespace mysql/innodb_index_stats which uses space ID: 2 at filepath: .\mysql\innodb_index_stats.ibd
InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file .\mysql\innodb_index_stats.ibd
InnoDB: We do not continue the crash recovery, because the table may become
InnoDB: corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log to it.
InnoDB: To fix the problem and start mysqld:
InnoDB: 1) If there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld cannot
InnoDB: open the file, you should modify the permissions.
InnoDB: 2) If the table is not needed, or you can restore it from a backup,
InnoDB: then you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal
InnoDB: crash recovery and ignore that table.
InnoDB: 3) If the file system or the disk is broken, and you cannot remove
InnoDB: the .ibd file, you can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf
InnoDB: and force InnoDB to continue crash recovery here.
```

Comment: Solution is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15767652/mysql-error-table-mysql-innodb-table-stats-not-found/16362871#16362871

Answer (score 0):

I would reinstall mysql server again, or the full xampp if its easier for you.

Comment: actually i guess you didnt anything (at least you change some auth settings or move some files)