# MAMP Pro 4 hangs with spinning wheel on each action

Tags: mamp, mamp-pro

Since upgrading from MAMP 3 to MAMP 4, the GUI hangs on each action. Clicking something like the menu occurs after around 30 seconds of the spinning wheel of death. This happens for any action within the interface. Running 10.12.2

This almost makes the software unusable, as I can't configure the interface to begin development.

Comment: Have run the uninstaller, removed everything, the done a fresh install. Still happening when I try an add a host or perform any action in the GUI. The program hangs.

Answer (score 2):

My experience was identical. Searching for some errors I ended up running Tools > Verify MySQL Databases... Among tons of OK'ed databases, several had errors - innodb_index_stats, innodb_table_stats, slave_master_info, slave_relay_log_info, and slave_worker_info.

From here a search lead me to [mysql error: Table “mysql”.“innodb_table_stats” not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15767652/mysql-error-table-mysql-innodb-table-stats-not-found).

So, I deleted all the .frm and .ibd of the tables above and I ran the [five-tables.sql](http://bugs.mysql.com/file.php?id=19725) file in Terminal: `source five-tables.sql`

Now MAMP Pro 4 runs smoothly and responsive.

Thanks, [Kay Nelson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/606294/kay-nelson).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing a search for MAMP in all parts of the file, and removed every reference to it, after running the uninstaller.

I also removed references to any PHP & memcache not in the /Applications/MAMP folder.

I renamed /Applications/MAMP to /Applications/MAMP-old and reinstalled. This set everything up fresh and appears to be working. Something with a conflict with a system binary or other package was causing the issue.