# Can't delete tables in phpMyAdmin because they aren't visible in the structure

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, mamp, mamp-pro

I've a local development environment with MAMP.
In this environment I'm using MySQL in version 5.6.35.

When I now want to import a database with phpMyAdmin, I get an internal server error everytime I try.

After some research I think there is a problem with the structure of the mysql database.

In the logs I found the following error:

> InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.

And an hint to this page: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html

There is also a link to a solution: 
[mysql error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15767652/mysql-error-table-mysql-innodb-table-stats-not-found)

My problem is, that I can't remove the tables (innodb_index_stats, innodb_table_stats, slave_master_info, slave_relay_log_info, slave_worker_info) from mysql. 
They show up in the sidebar but not in the structure itself.

[image]

And if I click on them, I get more errors:

[image]

What I could do and already did is to remove the .frm & .ibd files of the tables above. But this had no effect.

Is there a way to repair or replace the mysql db?

I also tried the replair and update tools from MAMP. Without success.

Comment: the obvious solution is to get a proper mysql client

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: because PHP mysadmin is a very poor imitation of a mysql client

Comment: I've tested Sequel Pro. It also shows the tables but couldn't open them because they don't exist

Comment: If you use a local myql server, then do not use phpmyadmin, but a standard desktop GUI (sqlyog, heidisql, etc)

Comment: In this case your MySQL instance may be broken. You may have to repair the MySQL database within your instance.

Comment: these are only windows clients. I'm using macOS. Is there no other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the problem after I also deleted the .ibd files in the folder: /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql56