# MAMP MySQL innodb and missing errors

Tags: mysql, database, drupal, mamp

I was running MAMP fine until I brought in one particular Drupal site. The site started white-screening, loading with no CSS, *and* occasionally throwing a PDO error, but only on the front site of the application. I could access the administration part of the site fine.

In the mysql error log I found a bunch of errors like `InnoDB: Error: Table "mysql"."innodb_table_stats" not found.` and ...`required persistent statistics storage is not present or is corrupted. Using transient stats instead.`

I dug through some of the Drupal views and found one that executes php from the database (big no-no!). I removed that from the database but I was still getting the same `innodb` errors.

Next I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15767652/mysql-error-table-mysql-innodb-table-stats-not-found). Similar sounding issue though different circumstances. I've seen a bunch of issues that seems related, though often involving upgrading to MySQL 5.6. The gist of the issue seems to be a list of tables in the `mysql` tables are improperly formatted. The solution suggested there and elsewhere is to delete the `.frm, .ibd` files associated with those tables, then recreate the tables using the query provided.

I did all that ^, and now all the sites in MAMP are sending 500 errors. Bigger than that, the error logs are totally silent, and I'm stuck with no idea where to turn.

NOTE: I uninstalled MAMP, reinstalled it, and the same thing occured.

Answer (score 0):

So, I will happily accept an answer that has a better explanation than what I'm giving here, but I "solved" this issue in the following manner:

1. The site was also running a module called "Sassy" that compiled CSS on the server, I was suspicious because of the missing CSS, so I configured the module to only compile when I explicitly tell it to.
2. I dropped and reimported each site's database.
3. I noticed as stated above I would get different responses on each page load. I persisted on going through the site, both admin and front side, by repeatedly reloading the pages.

In conclusion, I'm no longer getting the `innodb` errors, pushing through and disabling a sketchy(IMO) module seems to have fixed the white screen and 500 errors and brought back the styling. Which brings me to the big question I have which is, why wasn't I getting any error messages in the logs?