# how to repair easyphp devserver mysql? mysqlcheck shows many errors

Tags: phpmyadmin, mysql-5.7, easyphp

How do I repair mysql installation?
I am in the process of migrating from easyphp devserver 14.1 to 17.
1. I have exported and imported my databases and created new instances of my database users.
2. I have created my vhosts
3. When I attempt to access a database through my php website I got error " mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1524): Plugin  is not loaded."
4. A search on google suggested I do a mysql_upgrade, so I tried that and got "innodb_table_stats not found"...
5. so I tried mysqlcheck and got this:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.471]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-binaries\dbserver\mysql5717x86x181218152537\bin"

C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-binaries\dbserver\mysql5717x86x181218152537\bin>mysqlcheck mysql -uroot
mysql.columns_priv                                 OK
mysql.db
warning  : Size of indexfile is: 8054      Should be: 5120
status   : OK
mysql.event                                        OK
mysql.func                                         OK
mysql.general_log                                  OK
mysql.help_category                                OK
mysql.help_keyword                                 OK
mysql.help_relation                                OK
mysql.help_topic                                   OK
mysql.innodb_index_stats
Error    : Table 'mysql.innodb_index_stats' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
mysql.innodb_table_stats
Error    : Table 'mysql.innodb_table_stats' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
mysql.ndb_binlog_index                             OK
mysql.plugin                                       OK
mysql.proc                                         OK
mysql.procs_priv                                   OK
mysql.proxies_priv
warning  : Table is marked as crashed
warning  : Size of indexfile is: 6550      Should be: 5120
warning  : Size of datafile is: 952       Should be: 693
error    : got error: 0 when reading datafile at record: 1
error    : Corrupt
mysql.servers
warning  : Size of indexfile is: 1283      Should be: 1024
status   : OK
mysql.slave_master_info
Error    : Table 'mysql.slave_master_info' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
mysql.slave_relay_log_info
Error    : Table 'mysql.slave_relay_log_info' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
mysql.slave_worker_info
Error    : Table 'mysql.slave_worker_info' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed
mysql.slow_log                                     OK
mysql.tables_priv                                  OK
mysql.time_zone                                    OK
mysql.time_zone_leap_second                        OK
mysql.time_zone_name                               OK
mysql.time_zone_transition                         OK
mysql.time_zone_transition_type                    OK
mysql.user
warning  : Table is marked as crashed
warning  : 1 client is using or hasn't closed the table properly
warning  : Size of indexfile is: 12379      Should be: 2048
warning  : Size of datafile is: 2357       Should be: 548
error    : Wrong bytesec: 100-115-45 at linkstart: 548
error    : Corrupt
```

C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-binaries\dbserver\mysql5717x86x181218152537\bin>

Comment: I've deleted my installation and re-installed devserver v17 .... left it vanilla. Couldn't even start the database server. 
Uninstalled it again. rebooted pc. installed again. started the database. ran mysqlcheck and it shows the same errors - I have not even logged on to phpmyadmin in this installation!

Comment: I found this link [mysql-error-table-mysql-innodb-table-stats-not-found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15767652/mysql-error-table-mysql-innodb-table-stats-not-found/16362871#16362871)

Comment: but still had probs - so tried to connect using HeidiSQL - when I tried to connect as root, it told me Table 'performance_schema.session_status' doesn't exist
Another search suggested I run   
 `mysql_upgrade -u root --force`

Answer (score 0):

the `mysql_upgrade -u root --force` seems to have worked. I can now connect and view the main mysql database via HeidiSQL and phpMyAdmin is allowing me to view Status and access the Variablesl